# How to loop an array variable to perform a function without writing the function for each instance?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that has a set of elements by id. Previously I defined each element or array (say p ) as p1, p2, p3, etc and it worked. But I just want to reduce code reuse. Help?

I tried to use for loop for the code below as a for loop but it keeps saying unexpected end of input

```
p1.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

//handle click for p2
p2.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

is there any way to get the output like this:

```
for ( i=0; i< 25; i++){
p[i].onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;`
}
```

This is what I have in my html:

```
<div class="image"><img id="p1" class="portraitImg" 
src="../img/portrait/p1.jpeg" alt="Portrait 1" /></div>
<div class="image"><img id="p2" class="portraitImg" 
src="../img/portrait/p2.jpeg" alt="Portrait 2" /></div>
```

Comment: If you can update your HTML, you can simplify this a lot by simply giving each of the buttons the same class. Then you only need a single function.

Comment: Using element.addEventListener is better than setting element.onClick

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have classes, just use those instead of the IDs

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("portraitImg");
   for(var x = 0;x<imgs.length;x++){
      imgs[x].addEventListener("click",function(){
      document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("modalImg").src = this.src;
      document.getElementById("captionText").innerHTML = this.alt;
   });
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/AAA.png" alt="1" class="portraitImg"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/000/fff.png" alt="e" class="portraitImg"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/000.png" alt="6" class="portraitImg"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/e33/fff.png" alt="3" class="portraitImg"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/AAA/fff.png" alt="2" class="portraitImg">

<img src="" id="modalImg">
<div id="modal"></div>
<div id="captionText"></div>
```

Comment: Take the anonymous function outside of the loop and name it.